# SEO implications of including style and script tags inside body?

Tags: html, xhtml, seo

I was wondering if there are any SEO side effects if I put my `<script>` and `<style>` tags anywhere other than in HEAD. Or is it just due to the XHTML rules that this is bad?

Comment: SEO isn't considered programming. You might like to ask this question on http://doctype.com/ which is for "Web design Q&A".

Comment: Aside -- would someone who's able to post to meta please suggest there that "belongs on doctype.com" be added to the radio options "Why should this question be closed?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just bad practice to do so. HTML is only used for semantically marking up the data on the page.

Styles are for defining how this data LOOKS.

Script is for defining how the page BEHAVES.

The three should be separated / coupled loosely.

As for SEO, I doubt it has any effect at all.

Answer (score 3):

It has no impact on SEO. Search engines typically ignore script and style blocks regardless of where you put them.

<style> must go in the <head> if you want to validate, but <script> can go nearly anywhere. Indeed, putting scripts at the bottom of the <body> is a common strategy for optimising load times. Either way, there is no difference between HTML4 and XHTML here.